# How to free up space on filesystem in /dev/sda2 root partition?

Tags: partitioning, root, home-directory

My root partition (`/dev/sda2`) always fills up. The folders with the largest capacity are `/usr` and `/var`. I need either a way to clear up space or to resize partitions without formatting. I do not have unallocated space on my disk and do not know what is being saved in `/` as opposed to `/home`. Any helpers?

```
zuzoute@zuzoute:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           387M  6.2M  381M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       9.1G  9.1G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.9G  160K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       475M  7.1M  468M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4       445G   42G  380G  10% /home
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           387M   60K  387M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your programs are stored in `/dev/sda2`, it grows every time you install a new program / install updates (which can and often do increase the size of programs). You have plenty of space in `/dev/sda4`, so decrease the size of `/dev/sda4`, then increase the size of `/dev/sda2`.

Boot into a live system so no partition is mounted, then open GParted. Make sure swap isn't used either (if you have a swap partition) by right-clicking it and choosing "swap off".

Then resize your partitions as you choose. Resizing from the right hand side of a partition is generally fast, resizing from the left and moving a partition is generally slow.

Keep in mind that playing with partitions is dangerous, especially if there is a power failure, so make sure to have a backup.

Comment: It worked fine, no formatting necessary and the swap partition automatically locked after it was turned off and moved. results:zuzoute@zuzoute:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           387M  6.2M  381M   2% /run
/dev/sda2        69G  6.8G   59G  11% /
tmpfs           1.9G  156K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       475M  7.1M  468M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4       385G   42G  324G  12% /home